# Show that $T(t)$ and $N(t)$ are Orthogonal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

If $r(t)$ is the smooth parametrization of a curve $C$ in 3-space, then the unit tangent and unit normal vectors are denoted as $T$ and $N$, and are given by:
$$T(t)=\frac{r'(t)}{||r'(t)||},N(t)=\frac{T'(t)}{||T'(t)||}$$
How do I show that $T(t)$ and $N(t)$ are orthogonal for all $t$ at which they are defined. I cannot assume anything about the binormal vector $B$, so I want to know how to do this without assuming so.

Comment: I added the "differential geometry" tag to your post.  Hope it's OK.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ T(t)\cdot N(t)={1\over\|T'(t)\|}T(t)\cdot T'(t)={1\over2\|T'(t)\|}{d\over dt}\left[ T(t)\cdot T(t)\right]=0$$

Because $T(t)\cdot T(t)={r'(t)\cdot r'(t)\over \|r'(t)\|^2}\equiv 1$

Comment: What does "Because <T(t),T(t)>=1" mean?

Comment: Dot product. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat So that's the same as saying $T(t)\bullet T(t)=1$?

Comment: Yup. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes. Though when I use the dot notation I prefer $T(t)\cdot T(t)$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Nice answer.

Comment: @Mikeal By saying $f(t)\equiv 1$ I mean $\forall t\ f(t)=1$, i.e. that the equality holds for all $t$.